# need help adding to jquery array e.target and passing to php

Tags: jquery, arrays

i'm new to jQuery, I need to add a variable name `cid` on to `$(e.target)` and pass it to `admin_comment.php`...

```
var cid = 'some id'; // need to add that to $(e.target) and serialize

$.post('submit/admin_comment.php',$(e.target).serialize(),function(msg){

}
```

the php file looks like this...

```
$arr = array();

$validates = Comment::admin_comment_return($arr);
```

`admin_comment_return` validates the text inputs and returns all fixed up.

i access them like this: `$arr['somefield'];`

can someone explain how i can add cid to the array and then access it in the php file using:

`$arr['cid']`

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
    var cid = 'some id'; // need to add that to $(e.target) and serialize

   var data=$(e.target).serializeArray()
$data.push{name:"id_name", value:cid}
$.post('submit/admin_comment.php',data,function(msg){}
```